# Lasso regression non-zero interaction terms with zero main terms

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, interaction, lasso

I have performed lasso regression for variable selection on a glm. The result is that there is an interaction term (weight*carage) that is significant, however the main values are not (using 1 sd lambda as the optimal penalty parameter).

I believe you are meant to include the main effects if the interactions are significant, despite what the lasso regression says.

My question is, what is a valid way of doing this? Could I re-fit a glm using just the parameters the lasso regression selected, plus the main effects? Unfortunately my code is not reproducible as we were given a data set for an assignment. But I have attached an image just for context. [image]

eg. model1 <- glm(Counts~age+carage+weight+weight:carage,data=data2, family = "poisson", offset=log(exposure))
model1

[image]

Comment: Welcome to CV! Whenever it's possible, it is better to paste code instead of inserting a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks! As I said, the code won't be reproducible as it is on a custom data set which I can't upload. Any help would be great though!

Comment: @sam But you could copy-and-paste the R code instead of using pictures (and use the "$\{ \,\}$" formatting button to make it look right), so the same content but potential more accessible to others